# How does Boba Fett's ship fly backwards?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

In *The Book of Boba Fett* chapter 4, we see:

> Slave I pulling itself up from the Sarlacc Pit with its thrusters(?) turned on and aimed up.

I've always assumed that the big, glowing things at the aft side of Star Wars ships are thrusters, yet Boba Fett's ship moves in the opposite direction from where they're pointed.  How?

Is the light being generated just "waste light" from the reaction powering the ship that generates anti-gravitons or something?  And if so, why the big, glowing things always pointed aft?

Comment: Those are indeed thrusters. They propel the ship forward. But don't forget that this is a universe where ships have anti-gravity propulsors are well.

Comment: @Valorum Okay, so then why are the thrusters on and glowing?  And I guess then that the anti-gravity repulsors are strong enough to overcome forward thrust from the thrusters?

Comment: Yup. They're on, but basically idle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The winglets to either side of the Slave I contain [repulsorlift](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Repulsorlift/Legends) generators. Note that they rotate such that stay roughly parallel to the ground during scenes where the Slave I is hovering over terrain. They provide the lift to hold the ship up.

[image]

> "Fins contain repulsor grilles for landing maneuvers"
> https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Slave_I/Legends